# SyntaxError: syntax error <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, syntax-error

Basically, since i have installed sync, pusher, fayer and redis the app hasn't loaded anything. For the past 2 days been trying to figure out these errors:

[image: I thin it's the two SYNTAX errors that are causing problems here.]

https://www.dropbox.com/s/04063s1o8dgy5sg/Screenshot%202014-02-13%2021.18.34.png (big picture)
Chrome developers tool also points to the rails,js HTML DOC first line. other than that i don't get any other errors in console ;/

Please help me to end this nightmare of an error

Comment: Please post plain text. The tiny text in the images is unreadable.

Comment: You shouldn't have `<!DOCTYPE html>` in a `.js` file. JS files should just contain Javascript, it shouldn't be wrapped in HTML.

Answer (score 1):

Your assets are not being processed/displayed correctly. There must be some problem with your assets or routes.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `rails.js` cannot be found and is instead rendering the `404 page` instead of the contents of your `rails.js` file. Try to fix the route to the javascript file and this should fix your problem.

Comment: thanks for help, basically i got rid of all of the errors by just getting rid of those parts. and it still not loading :D i'm just gona roll back 8 days of work and start again :)